# Creating app scoped external content type using Provider Hosted App in sharepoint 2013 using visual studio 2012

Tags: external-content-type, visual-studio-2012, provider-hosted-app

[image]

I am creating provider hosted app in Visual Studio 2012 using app scoped external content type having OData with Northwind url

App manifest start page url :

```
ODataNewAppWeb/Pages/Default.aspx
```

In XML it is:

```
 <StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx</StartPage>
```

When I am deploying app pressing F5 the app gets deployed successfully.

Now I am changing my start page url in App manifest like this:

```
ODataNewApp/Lists/Employees
```

In XML it looks like:

```
<StartPage>~appWebUrl/Lists/Employees</StartPage>
```

When I am deploying app pressing F5 the app gets register SOD error.

I have followed all the steps like:

1. Creating app domain
2. Starting all the required services
3. Creating root site collection

But still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Shyam

I have implemented your problem on my system. And its working just fine. I am able to access Employees list. My AppManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
 Name="SharePointApp1"
 ProductID="{eb66d96e-501a-4256-bc2e-db70acbe3f7b}"
 Version="1.0.0.0"
 SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0"
 >
 <Properties>
<Title>SharePointApp1</Title>
<StartPage>~appWebUrl/Lists/Employees?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
</Properties>

<AppPrincipal>
  <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />
 </AppPrincipal>
<AppPermissionRequests>
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection"     Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
</App>
```

Make sure that you have set the Permissions right.

Hope This helps,
Deepa

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Deepa ,

I am looking for creation of External Content Type in Provider hosted App.because there is no any option in Appweb project to add the External content type.

Please help me for implement the External Content Type in Provider Hosted App.

Comment: I am afraid this is not right section for comments. Only valid answers are allowed here. If you need to ask any query to the author of an answer/question, then you need to write comment. And for writing comments you need to attain at least 50 reputations.